# Printing GetWindowTextA is wrong when printing outside function

Tags: c++, winapi, char, printf

I'm quite new to C++, coming from C# background, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I have the following function for getting the title of a window by handle.

```
char* GetWindowTitle(HWND hwnd) {
    char winTitle[56];
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd, winTitle, sizeof(winTitle));
    printf("Title: %s\n", winTitle);

    return winTitle;
}
```

The `printf` in this function correctly outputs `Title: a.txt - Notepad`.

But if I do the same with the return from the function:

```
printf("Title: %s\n", GetWindowTitle(hwnd));
```

The output is now "Title: `÷S"

What's causing this different behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the address of something that is local to the function. It only exists for the duration of that function.

```
char* GetWindowTitle(HWND hwnd) {
    char winTitle[56];  <====== this is destroyed when the function ends
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd, winTitle, sizeof(winTitle));
    printf("Title: %s\n", winTitle);

    return winTitle;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
#include <string>

std::string GetWindowTitle(HWND hwnd) {
    char winTitle[56];
    GetWindowTextA(hwnd, winTitle, sizeof(winTitle));
    printf("Title: %s\n", winTitle);

    return std::string(winTitle);
}
```

This will allocate a `std::string` on the heap. Once you no longer reference it in the calling code, it will be deleted.

To display this string with `printf()`, do:

```
printf("Title: %s\n", GetWindowTitle(hwnd).c_str());
```

Though, you should get out of the habit of using C-style I/O (`printf()`, etc). To display this string with C++-style I/O, do:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Title: " << GetWindowTitle(hwnd) << std::endl;
```

If you intend to write a lot of C ++ code, learn to use:

- `std::string` (`string` in C#)
- `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` (class object reference in C#)
- `std::vector` (`List` in C#)
- `std::map` (`Dictionary` in C#)

Comment: "*this will allocate a `std::string` on the heap*" - that is misleading. The `std::string` itself is not on the heap, but its payload *might* be. With SSO (short string optimization), it *might not* be on the heap at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know but I didnt want to go into huge details. Saying it works like string in c# (I am C# and C++ dev) conveys the right dynamics to OP.

Comment: The equivalent to `string` in C# is `std::wstring` in C++. *"get out of the habit of using C-style I/O"* - Indeed. Though the replacement shouldn't be C++' I/O streams. C++20 introduced a [formatting library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) that combines the succinct formatting DSL of `printf` with the type safety of I/O streams. And it's much, **much** faster than I/O streams. Also, a key takeaway here should be: Do not ignore warnings. The [`/WX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level) compiler option is very effective.

Comment: @IInspectable he is using ascii not wide chars. That would have involved a lot more info thatn OP needs. I hate cout << ..<<... so I am glad theres a replacement, TIL

Comment: *"he is using ascii"* - No, he isn't. He's calling into the ANSI API. ANSI uses the ambient character set, which may or may not be the expected character set. This is not in general desirable. But that is really besides the point: `string` in C# stores UTF-16 encoded text. `std::string` in C++, on the other hand, is used to store anything, ASCII, ANSI, UTF-8, etc., but **not** UTF-16. That's what `std::wstring` (or `std::u16string`) is for.